# I have some issues using chromedriver in vba, sessions not created anymore

Tags: vba, selenium

I have some issues using chromedriver in VBA. I am not able to launch chromedriver, the error message appears as below:

```
SessionsNotCreatedEror 
Sessions not created exeption from unknow error : Runtime.exectionContextCreated has invalid 'context'(..)
```

I have the last version of Selenium, ChromeDriver and Google chrome(85).

I try to downgrade my chromedriver but it not works.

Could you please advise ?

Regards,

Comment: chromedriver version must match chrome version. You might try downgrading both to a version you know worked. Selenium basic is no longer updated AFAIK and I haven't tested with more recent versions of chrome. Others might have. I'd be suspicious of underlying NET framework being used as well but no evidence to back that up.

Comment: @Nikkei225 - Welcome to SO. You should always always share what code you have tried , so that it will be easy to debug your issue. Also as QHarr mentioned please check your chrome browser version it should be compatible with your chromedriver version.